# php upload multiple file with predefined file name

Tags: php

I want to upload multiple files with predefined file name, is it possible? how to retrieve the name from php?

How to retrieve the name 'doc1' and 'doc2' from the php?

My code:

```html
<?
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1024; //1MB
$path = "uploads/doc/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
             }
             else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files
                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                     $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
                 }
            }
        }
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Doc1: <input type="file" id="file" name="files['doc1']" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" /><br>
    Doc2: <input type="file" id="file" name="files['doc2']" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you change the file names after upload in the move_uploaded_file function

Comment: You could name it in PHP script. You don't need to make your HTML code to complicated. Multiple arrays and capable to upload multiple files?! (That's not even work cause the name is not a multiple files array). Use Doc1: `<input type="file" id="file" name="doc1" accept="image/*" />` and run the PHP script twice instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do check php code below that will return all details of files you uploaded.

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
 {  
    echo "File Names:<br>Doc1= ".$_FILES['files']['name']["'doc1'"];
    echo "<br>Doc2= ".$_FILES['files']['name']["'doc2'"];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "File Types:<br>Doc1= ".$_FILES['files']['type']["'doc1'"];
    echo "<br>Doc2= ".$_FILES['files']['type']["'doc2'"];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "Tmp Name:<br>Doc1= ".$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']["'doc1'"];
    echo "<br>Doc2= ".$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']["'doc2'"];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "Error:<br>Doc1= ".$_FILES['files']['error']["'doc1'"];
    echo "<br>Doc2= ".$_FILES['files']['error']["'doc2'"];
    echo "<br><br>";

    echo "Size:<br>Doc1= ".$_FILES['files']['size']["'doc1'"];
    echo "<br>Doc2= ".$_FILES['files']['size']["'doc2'"];
    echo "<br><br>";
 }
?>
```